# Retrieve parameter value in attribute directive when using a class model/typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

You can see a snippet of some code i am working on below.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('maskedInput', [
    function() {
      return {
        scope: {
          mymask: '=maskedInput'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          console.log('attributes', attrs);
          scope.$watch('mymask', function(newVal) {
            console.log(newVal);
            elem.inputmask(newVal);
          }, true)
        }
      }
    }
  ])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.mask = {
        mask: '99999[-9999]',
        greedy: false
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https:/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h3>Mask</h3>
    <p>Mask: 99999[-9999]</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" masked-input="mask">
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="mask.mask" />
    <br />{{mask}}
    <br/>{{test}}
    </td>
</body>
```

I am working on recreating this in typescript.  Here's what I have so far.

```
class InputMaskDirective implements ng.IDirective {
constructor () {
    var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
    directive.restrict = 'A';
    directive.scope = { mymask : '=maskedInput' };
    directive.link = (scope: any, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
        scope.$watch('mymask', function (newVal) {
            element.inputmask(newVal);
        }, true);
    };
    return directive;
   }
 }

 export = InputMaskDirective;
```

We are using requirejs as well, so when we instanciate the class in our app.ts file, we do something like

```
import MaskedInputDirective = require("src/common/directives/inputmaskdirective");
var application: angular.IModule = angular.module("application",[InjectionStuffHere]);
application.directive("maskedInput",[MaskedInputDirective]);
export = application;
```

The problem i forsee is that because of the "class" structure of requirejs and the typescript code, in theory a user can name the directive whatever they want.

Wouldn't that break the code with the scope?  Since the scope is looking for the masked-input, the snake cased name of the directive, to be in the html, if the user named it something else, how would it know the correct name?

I've tried attrs to see if I can get something out of it, but no luck.  Do I just have to hope that the users don't muck with it when they create the code?

Answer (score 1):

I follow [this](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/typescript-angular/js) structure when writing angular directives in typescript.

Factories and Directives are created as functions, where directive-functions return a `:ng.IDirective` instead.

```
function inputMaskDirective(): ng.IDirective {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {myMask: "=maskedInput"},
//and on
  }
}
```

if you have any injects add them to the property`$inject` of the function

```
inputMaskDirective.$inject = ["someService"];
```

Comment: Problem there is that you still could have any name you want for the implementation of the directive. Say they added it to the app as angular.module('myApp').directive('myFunkyMaskedInput', inputMaskDirective()).  Wouldn't the scope not work anymore? Doesn't the "=maskedInput" need to match the name of the implementation?  It seems to me that this puts a required knowledge of the implementation that I would have expected there to be a way around.

Comment: I usually add the directive to the module in the same file the directive code exists. Having the directives and services require the module. wouldn't that work?